# SATA Hard drive not detected after disconnecting it and connecting it again

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, sata, cable

- HDD 1: Not working
- HDD 2: Working

I accidentally disconnected the *SATA to motherboard cable*, with the power suply cable still attached (from HDD 1). It crashed my Ubuntu, and when I connected the SATA cable back to HDD 1, it doesn't work.

The computer can't see any of my HDDs, but when I disconnect the SATA HDD 1 cable again, it sees my other drive (HDD 2)!

HDD 1 is making a spinning noise.

Comment: Just as a comment, SATA supports hotplug per spec and it's unlikely that the drive was damaged. I did that several times myself and everything has worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an external enclosure/case to see if it can read anything

just to  clarify what part of the computer doesnt see the hdd? the BIOS or the OS/LiveCD?

Comment: None of them sees the hdd.

Comment: here this is all you need, and im sure they'll ship it to your country. http://cgi.ebay.com/USB-2-0-IDE-SATA-S-ATA-2-5-3-5-HD-HDD-Adapter-Cable-/180550148600?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a09a0a1f8

Comment: also try a different computer maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If BIOS can't see the drive and you already tried madmaze's suggestion, the last ditch is switching out the controller board with something similar.  Check fleabay/newegg/tiger for similar drives.

Comment: Is buying external cases are the only solution? Becouse they are expensive in my country

Comment: not a lot else you can do here.  imo something fried when you hot swapped a non-hotswappable drive

Answer (score 0):

If possible you should try using a external HDD case, or a HD Dock of some sort.

Comment: No, but i have tried to connect it to other PC. It doesn't work there too.